# Why doesn't thin log timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I'm using Thin and in trying to debug an issue where the Thin server exits due to an error I was looking  at the thin log.  Unfortunately the Thin log doesn't have any timestamps.  Looking at the Thin code I found this in thin/logging.rb:

```
# Simple formatter which only displays the message.
# Taken from ActiveSupport
class SimpleFormatter < Logger::Formatter
  def call(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{String === msg ? msg : msg.inspect}\n"
  end
end
```

Does anyone know why Thin doesn't display the timestamp?  Any suggestions for a good way to add timestamps to the Thin logs without modifying the library itself?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a file in config/initializers and monkey patching the thin code worked well for me.  Hope this helps someone else.  I'm still curious why Thin authors decided to exclude timestamps.

I created the file config/initializers/thin_customization.rb with the following contents:

```
require 'logger'

#monkey patch thin to add timestamps to logging
module Thin
  module Logging
    class SimpleFormatter < Logger::Formatter
      def call(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
        "#{timestamp} #{String === msg ? msg : msg.inspect}\n"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I created a pull request with your suggestion at https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/pull/351